# Are there well-established ways of mixing different inputs (e.g. image and numbers)?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, architecture

I am interested in the possibility of having extra input along with the main data. For instance, a medical application that would rely mostly on an image: how could one also account for sex, age, etc.?

It is certainly possible to put the output of a CNN and other data into, say, a densely connected network; but it seems inefficient. Are there well-established ways of doing something like this?

Answer (score 4):

A more efficient way would be creating a multi input model, with something like this:

```
___________    _____________
|__Image__|    |Other input|            
_____|_____     _____|_____
|___CNN___|     |__Dense___|
_____|______    _____|______
|_Features1_|   |_Features2_|
         __|_____|__
         |__Merge___|
         _____|______
         |___Dense__|
         _____|_____
         |__Output__|
```

However, you could also combine the unstructured data to the image, as stated in the quora answer:

> #### The out-of-the-box method:
>
> If you want to just take your CNN library and use it without much
>   thought, there's an easy way to do it.
>
> Your image has “channels”: red blue and green channels, for example.
>   Just add another channel for each unstructured feature. Those channels
>   will just be 2D-arrays whose entries are all the same value: the value
>   of your outside feature.
>
> It means more memory and more parameters though. If you have a lot of
>   unstructured data, this can become prohibitively expensive.
>
> #### The more efficient method (and still not hard):
>
> You use one or more deconvolutional filters to bring the unstructured
>   data up to the size of the structured data, concatenate them along the
>   channel dimension, and keep going as if nothing happened.

Source: [How can l train a CNN with extra features other than the pixels? (Quora)](https://www.quora.com/How-can-l-train-a-CNN-with-extra-features-other-than-the-pixels)